# How to avoid xml element in serilization of emf model to xml?

Tags: xml, eclipse, uml, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I am trying to serialize my emf model.My emf model structure is as shown below
   [image]

If we generate a xml from this the result will look something like below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <model:abcs xmlns:model="http:///model.ecore">
      <abc>
        <name>somename</name>
        <xyz>
          <min>20</min>
          <max>100</max>
        </xyz>
      </abc>
    </model:abcs>
```

I want to remove XYZ tag from the xml .So the generated xml will look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <model:abcs xmlns:model="http:///model.ecore">
      <abc>
        <name>somename</name>
         <min>20</min>
          <max>100</max>
       </abc>
    </model:abcs>
```

Any pointer on this will be helpful.

Comment: But, isn't it part of your model right there?

Comment: @nitind yes its part of model but can i remove the tag element called xyz.I mean is there any possibility